# Unexpected behavior in GDB output

Tags: gdb

So I beginning to learn how to use GDB and I'm getting some unexpected behavior in my output.

I'm running GDB on the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    unsigned int value1, abs_value1, abs_value2, abs_value3;
    int value2, value3;
    char myarray[10]; 

    printf("Enter 10 characters:");
    fgets(myarray, 11, stdin); 

    printf("Enter an integer between 0 and 10,000:");
    scanf("%d", &value1);
    abs_value1 = abs(value1);

    printf("Enter an integer between -10,000 and 0:");
    scanf("%d", &value2);
    abs_value2 = abs(value2);

    printf("Enter an integer between -10,000 and 10,000:");
    scanf("%d", &value3);
    abs_value3 = abs(value3);

    // set breakpoint here
}
```

The values I entered are...

```
value1 = 578
value2 = -1123
value3 = 999
```

On first two go around on testing some commands i got what seems to be some interesting behavior

```
x/1d &abs_value3 : -25
x/1d &abs_value1 : 66
```

On the last two go arounds i starting getting some expected output

```
x/1d &abs_value3 : 999
x/1d &abs_value1 : 578
```

I used the same program on all tests and ran the tests the same way but I'm little worried about the inconsistencies in the output. I hope this makes sense, I'm just wondering what could be the cause

For clarification I am posting a screen shot. The highlighted part shows the same command being used but has different output later on

[image]

Comment: Please edit the specific problem into the question. What is the unexpected issue?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm little worried about the inconsistencies in the output.

You are not telling the *whole* story, which makes it harder to guess what's happened.

The following command: `x/1d addr` tells GDB to examine one *unit* (of memory) located at `addr`, and print it as a decimal number.

But how large is that *unit*?

Without explicit specification, it *depends* on *previously executed commands*. From [gdb documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Memory.html):

> Each time you specify a unit size with x, that size becomes the default unit the next time you use x.

So given your "inconsistent" output:

> `x/1d &abs_value3 : -25`
> `x/1d &abs_value3 : 999`

and also knowing that `999 == 0x3e7` and that `(signed char)0xe7 == -25`, we can deduce that you used `x/1b` before using `x/1d` which produced the first output, but did not use `x/1b` before `x/1d` which produced the second output.

To avoid confusing yourself, *always* specify the size you want to examine.

If you had used `x/dw` (or `x/1dw`, but 1 is the default), the same output would have been printed each time.